# EndSale() function in Solidity fails

Tags: token, solidity

I have the following solidity code:

```
function endSale() public {
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));

    // UPDATE: Let's not destroy the contract here
    // Just transfer the balance to the admin
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

For some reason, it fails when I invoke the function. I'm using pragma solidity 0.6.0;
Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Since you didn't provide the rest of your .sol, I'm assuming tokenContract and address(this) refer to the same contract or are they separate contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this line of code

```
require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));
```

tells your contract to transfer its entire balance to the admin address, requiring that the result of the call to transfer evaluates to true, otherwise the function fails and the state reverts, preventing further execution.

Then, calling:

```
msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

attempts to transfer the total balance of this contract, again.

One thing to note, **require** statements can ensure the conditions of the contract's state are met **before** the body of the function is even executed, when declared and used as a **modifier** statement declared in the contract.

The other thing is, calls to **.transfer** do not return anything, they only propagate errors that occur. There is an alternative work around using the function **.send()** which **does** return a bool but it is not very syntactically appealing and its use is not recommended, unless necessary or you know what you are doing, since the programmer is required to explicitly required to call **revert()** in the event the call returns false and can cause severe bugs if neglected.

so in effect, calling

```
require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));
```

should always terminate with an exception, since it neither evaluates to true nor false and solidity has no concept of the ubiquitous NULL value in most other programming languages.

You can determine if this is the case by adding a string as the second parameter to the  **require** call, which will output a log message when the condition evaluates to **false**.

Then, if for some reason that isn't what is terminating execution, you are also attempting to transfer the balance of your contract, before calling your method to transfer its balance, again.

This is a major logical error/bug and would attempt to cause a transfer of the same amount again (after the contract has already done so) which is referred to as a **double payment**, but it should no longer have a balance, since it has been transferred to the admin, via the previous call inside **require();**.

A reasonable solution then might look similar to this:

```
modifier onlyAdmin(){
    require(msg.sender == admin, "only an admin may access this method");
    _;
}

modifier nonZeroBalance(){
    require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) > 0 wei, "contract requires a non-zero balance to execute");
    _;
}

function endSale() public onlyAdmin nonZeroBalance {
    //
    // require this contract to have a non-zero balance (or any other appropriate value as required) before accepting transfers since,
    // it's a waste of gas to transfer nothing
    //
    // now transfer should work alright and will throw and exception,
    // should .transfer fail in any way
    uint256 previousBalance = address(this).balance;
    //
    msg.sender.transfer(previousBalance);
    //
    //transaction complete, this contract's balance is now 0
    //
    //perform additional sanity checks to ensure this contract and the admin's
    //state are what should be expected, otherwise call revert() or throw()
}
```